# Sublime text 3 win 7 TernJS and tern_for_sublime install issue

Tags: javascript, plugins, sublimetext3, ternjs

I want Sublime to jump to variable definition (for method it works with F12), and to find all variable/method references/calls. Also, to provide nice autocomplete.

I try to install TernJS and tern_for_sublime and none of them work.

According to [link,](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/TernJS) TernJS  is Deprecated.

With tern_for_sublime I get error that I need to install npm package manually. First image below appears when I started sublime, second immediately after sublime is started and third one when I tried to use any command from tern_for_sublime package.

I do not know what does it mean. I check and I already have Node.js and npm installed. I also tried to install tern_for_sublime from package control and manually from git repository.

According to documentation:

```
"The plugin will load its settings from Tern.sublime-settings (found in
Preferences > Package Settings > Tern), and recognized the following 
settings:

tern_argument_hints (boolean, defaults to false)"
```

There is no this and any other setting in my sublime ternjs. I checked I have "AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\tern_for_sublime" package which I got from github.

Does anyone have the same problem with this, or have some other plugin to recommend me ?

[image: Dialog appears when sublime starts]
[image: When sublime starts dialog appears]

[image: When try to use tern_for_sublime comand]

Comment: Did you follow the setup instructions for [`tern_for_sublime`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/tern_for_sublime)? What was the exact text of the error, and what were you doing when it appeared? *"None of them work"* is not a description of the problem. *What* doesn't work? Did you try opening the preferences files to see if you could fix anything?

Comment: Sorry, I updated my question now with more information, I hope i will help.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the location said in the error: C:...AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\tern_for_sublime. and then open a cmd window there in that directory. Then type

```
    npm install
```

that should install ternjs.